# Error " No matching distribution found for setuptools>=42" with pip3 install

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I’m following [this tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) to build a python pip package. The only difference is that my package has a C source file.

It specifies that we have to create a `pyproject.toml` file containing

```
[build-system]
requires = [
    "setuptools>=42", 
    "wheel"
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

Building the package succeeds, but installing the package with the command `$ python3 -m pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --no-deps qjson2json` fails with the error

```
$ python3 -m pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --no-deps qjson2json
Looking in indexes: https://test.pypi.org/simple/
Collecting qjson2json
  Downloading https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/99/2d/ab24cc0a2a1473f6d3d21dd011199741c33b8a7d7fc67682822ce9f40b84/qjson2json-0.0.0.tar.gz (19 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-sizklrvy/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ -- 'setuptools>=42' wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (3 lines):
  Looking in indexes: https://test.pypi.org/simple/
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=42 (from versions: none)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=42
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-sizklrvy/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ -- 'setuptools>=42' wheel Check the logs for full command output.
```

But I do have the  latest version of `setuptools`.

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /home/meessen/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (53.0.0)
```

In [the documentation of `setuptools`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_meta.html) the content of the `pyproject.toml` file is shown to be

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

Who is right ? Is it safe to drop the `>=42` ?

**Edit 1**: I tried removing the `>=42` and it also fails with the error:

```
$ python3 -m pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --no-deps qjson2json
Looking in indexes: https://test.pypi.org/simple/
Collecting qjson2json
  Downloading https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/46/c715aa93b6589a871c3243982a170e448bda4e75cc90224465921e88f1c1/qjson2json-0.0.2.tar.gz (19 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-8tgcmoy_/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ -- setuptools wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (3 lines):
  Looking in indexes: https://test.pypi.org/simple/
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools (from versions: none)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-8tgcmoy_/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ -- setuptools wheel Check the logs for full command output.
```

I don’t know where are the logs that I could check.

Could it be an error in my `setup.cfg` ?

```
[metadata]
name = qjson2json
version = 0.0.2
url = https://github.com/qjson/qjson-py3
maintainer = Christophe Meessen
maintainer_email = christophe@meessen.net
description = Converts QJSON, a human readable JSON, into JSON
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
keywords = JSON, config, QJSON
license = BSD 3-Clause License
license_file = LICENSE.txt
classifiers =
    License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3
    Operating System :: OS Independent
    Topic :: Utilities

[options]
packages = qjson
python_requires = >=3.5
install_requires =
  requests
  importlib; python_version == "3.5"
```

**Edit 2**: another strange behavior of my setup is that when I run `python3 -m build` I see

```
$ python3 -m build
Found existing installation: setuptools 44.0.0
Uninstalling setuptools-44.0.0:
  Successfully uninstalled setuptools-44.0.0
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.36.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached setuptools-53.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (784 kB)
Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools
Successfully installed setuptools-53.0.0 wheel-0.36.2
...
```

Why does it find setuptools 44 and not 53 which is already installed ?

I even installed it with `sudo`.

Comment: You can have the latest `setuptools` which is `53.0.0`

Comment: @ParthS007 It is installed as I showed in the question.

Comment: `python3 -m pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple/ --no-deps qjson2json`

Comment: @phd thanks. This solves the problem with setuptools. Is it possible to have an explanation ?

Comment: @chmike See my answer in the linked duplicate (at the top of your question).